# How to determine if a block is run synchronously or not at runtime

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am working with a library (Fast Image Cache) that has a method that takes a block that it may or may not call synchronously.

I am trying to determine which is the case within the block using the following code:

```
__block BoolSleeve* sync = [[BoolSleeve alloc] init];
sync.value = YES;
[object block:^{
    if (sync.value)
        NSLog(@"sync");
    else
        NSLog(@"async");
}];
sync.value = NO;
```

However, so far this and many related variations have failed to print "async" when expected.

BTW, BoolSleeve is:

```
@interface BoolSleeve : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL value;

@end
```

Comment: I don't think your test is valid. Theoretically, it is possible for the block to run asynchronously, and still finish before you set `sync.value` to NO in the other thread. It's a race condition.

Comment: Blocks are absolutely not by definition asynchronous. They're just regular functions with some captured state wrapped in an object.

Comment: Try printing the result of `[NSThread isMainThread]` in your block.

Comment: @BlackRider, in this situation I am able to test that that isn't occurring.

Comment: Blocks can be run synchronously or asynchronously. In fact the exact same block could be executed numerous times, sometimes synchronously and sometimes asynchronously, although you generally wouldn't have a reason to do that.

Comment: The information is clearly stated in the product's documentation: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-image-cache/documentation/Classes/FICImageCache.html

Comment: @Jeremy I'm not exactly sure what you referring to.  But, the method in question may act either sync or async.  I'm not asking about the library, but rather which it chose to do at run time.

Comment: Which method of image cache are you referring to? You stated that you are working with fast image cache that has a method, but didn't specify which.  Or, are you referring to your own method?

Comment: @Jeremy retrieveImageForEntity:withFormatName:completionBlock:  "If the requested image already exists in the image cache, then the completion block is immediately called synchronously on the current thread. If the requested image does not already exist in the image cache, then the completion block will be called asynchronously on the main thread as soon as the requested image is available."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was quoted from the documentation:

> If the requested image already exists in the image cache, then the completion block is immediately called synchronously on the current thread. If the requested image does not already exist in the image cache, then the completion block will be called asynchronously on the main thread as soon as the requested image is available.

Given the above information, if you wish to determine if it will be run synchronously on the current thread, or asynchronously on the main thread, you will need to know only 1 thing:

*Does the image currently exist in cache?*

To find out, call the `imageExistsForEntity:withFormatName:` method of your object.  Doing so will let you know if it exists in cache.  With that information, you will then be able to determine if it *will* run synchronously on the current thread, or asynchronously on the main thread.

The issue that you are having, I believe, is that you are attempting to make that determination after the block has been called.  By this time, there is **no way for you to know** since the framework doesn't hand you any information regarding this.  Instead, you will have to determine before your method call.

So, your code might look something like this:

```
...
BOOL isSynchronousOnCurrentThread = [object imageExistsForEntity...];
...
[object block:^{
    if (isSynchronousOnCurrentThread)
        NSLog(@"Is Synchronous on current thread");
    else
        NSLog(@"Is Asynchronous on main thread");
}];
```

But, be careful - the framework developer may later decide to change that.  And since you will have married your code with a decision process only known to the framework, then your code could possibly break.

**Note:**
To determine which is the current thread, you can call `[NSThread currentThread]`.

**As an aside:**
I am curious why you would need to know that (for my own dark and sinister reasons).  Perhaps there is a better way to do what you want, or maybe is indicative of a larger problem.

Comment: I'll try this, but it still would be nice to know why the above code isn't working or how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, so a bit embarrassing, but my problem was much more pedestrian.  I have two versions of my method that is making this call and I was modifying the incorrect one.  I assumed the problem lied within some fundamental lack of understanding of mine in blocks rather than something more simple.

Comment: Eureka!  Sounds like you are on the right track.  Happy coding!

Comment: Ya, thanks for the help.  Actually, trying your direct method is what clued me into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread])
```

That will let you know if what you're running is executing on the main thread or not. If not, you can use the following before your block and in your block to get the current thread for each:

```
[NSThread currentThread]
```

Then you can compare the two to see if they're the same thread or not.

Comment: Is it the case that a async call necessarily is on a different thread?

Comment: @aepryus I guess it could be that its execution is delayed until a later time on the same thread, which is very common. You're the one who posted the question, so is that the case here? You should append this and any other details you can add to your question.

Comment: I have no reason to believe the block whether run sync or async isn't being run not the main thread.

Comment: @aepryus If you use what I posted, it will let you know if the block is run on the main thread or not. Otherwise, if it is running the block at a delayed time on the same thread, then your code above should be returning "async". So if your code above always says "sync" and `[NSThread isMainThread]` is always YES, then your code is being run synchronously on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

You should have control over how you call your blocks, it shouldn't be up to the block scope to decide what to do.

Dispatch asynchronous:

```
 void
 dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, void (^block)(void));
```

Dispatch synchronous:

```
 void
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_t queue, void (^block)(void));
```

e.g.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
   // background operation
 });

 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // synchronous operation
 });

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // runs the block in the next run-loop on the main thread
 });
```

You can get more advanced by creating your own queues and managing what gets dispatched on them, see for more  : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/dispatch_queue_create.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dispatch_queue_create

Comment: The library writer in this instance chose to make the method act either sync or async (based on other conditions).  I'm trying to determine which was used within the block at runtime.